# OpenAPI 3.0 swagger generated by Java - allow nullable ref object

Tags: java, swagger, openapi

I am trying to generate valid swagger using @Schema annotation in Java (io.swagger.core.v3) that would accept null or ref object.

So for example api defined with:

```
public class User {
  private int age;
  private Address address;
}
public class Address {
  private String city;
}
```

should work whether client sends nothing (ommits address entirely) or empty object ("address": {}) (both of those work) but it should also work client includes "address" = null in request

If I do not specify anything then I am left with this definition:

```
"application/json": {
          "schema": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
              "age": {
                "type": "integer",
                "nullable": true
              },
              "address": {
                "$ref": "#/components/schemas/Address"
              }
            }
          }

"schemas": {
  "Address": {
    "type": "object",
      "city": {
        "type": "string"
      }
  }
}
```

Adding @Schema(nullable=true) does not work because while it generates this:

```
"address": {
   "$ref": "#/components/schemas/Address",
   "nullable"=true
 }
```

It gets overriden by ref anyway.

Now, I know how I could solve it through edit of this Swagger directly. I could use anyOf and specify 'null'.

```
"anyOf": [
    { "type": "null" },
    { "$ref": "#/components/schemas/Address" }
]
```

This absolutely works but I was unable to figure out how to get to this outcome with @Schema annotation because anyOf accepts only classes.

The only other solution I have is to use @Schema(nullable=true) directly above class Address but I am working with much more complex objects than this sample example and I would prefer to have control flow inside the outer object that encapsulates API rather than common objects that are shared across multiple APIs.

Has anyone solved something similar with swagger being generated directly from Java definitions and annotations?

Comment: Since Address is an entity/schema of it's own, imho it's just good practice to add `@Schema(nullable=false)` to the correspnding field. Afaik it's also the only way to SPECIFY that null is a valid value. Another less specific/transparent approach that I would rather not advice is to keep address an optional property and handle null values when unmarshalling.

Comment: I tried this but it does not work. I talk about it in my post, it generates "nullable": true right next to ref itself but it gets ignored. I looked it up and it is apparently not a bug but feature of swagger (https://swagger.io/docs/specification/using-ref). All sibling properties are ignored if $ref is used.

Comment: Did you test to add `@Schema(nullable=true)` to class `Address`?

Comment: Can I ask why does it need to be nullable? If it's a required field then you can just make it optional, and if it's optional already then it doesn't need to be nullable, users can just leave it out.

Comment: According to [this answer](https://github.com/acacode/swagger-typescript-api/issues/39#issuecomment-604365713) nullable is fine nex to $ref